# Adding related products to Magento 1.5

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I know absolutely nothing about how Magento builds its pages. How do I add related products to the detail page of a product? I've added related products on the backend, but nothing shows up in the frontend.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign `Related Products` to Particual Product from `Product Edit form` in backend. As you are saying you already assigned these products from backend but still it is not showing in frontend then possible reason may be any of one:

1. Make sure selected related producs are enabled and not out of stock
2. If you are using customize theme then it may possible that Related Product block is removed or commented from theme files.

You can check below post for set up Related Products in backend:
https://stuntcoders.com/magento-tutorials/magento-products/adding-related-products/

Comment: Thank you, i'll look into #2. They products are enabled and don't use stock. They do show up if i place them in the regular categories page, they just aren't showing up on the detail page. It is a custom theme so you may be right on that one. Thanks!